# webkit renders last px of border:1px dotted; oddly

Tags: css, border, pixel, dotted-line

in webkit safari and chrome ive found that they render the last px of the css rule `border:1px dotted;` oddly it kind of combines the last 2 pixels into 1 so you get a black mark at the end of the line ..?

has any one else encountered this / got a work arround for it ? please see attached image bellow

[image]

Comment: it probably has to do with the width of the element you're adding a dotted border to. if the width isn't quite wide enough, the last pixel probably combines with the one before it, skipping the space

Comment: It's due to the way that different browsers draw "dotted" corners. See: http://jsfiddle.net/b6Qgn/1/

Comment: @jawad the image is there its the bit that says perty with the line under it.. sorry its a bit hard too see because its white on white

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give it a `border-right: 1px solid transparent;` style: http://jsfiddle.net/4CktD/

It's weird, but hey, it works.

Comment: I'm getting a double dot on the left instead of on the right. Plus it doesn't work with zoom and borders wider than 1px - it just cuts a corner of the last dot, which looks even worse.