# border dotted merge at end on rounded values

Tags: html, css, border, dotted-line

I am working on a site and struck on the code below

```
border:1px dotted black;
```

i need exactly a **200px** width of dotted border but it produce a 
 merged ending. Please look at the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/krish/mmvVH/1/).  if i put **199px** it was good at look. my question is Any way to make it look good(without merging ending) in **200px** width?

Thank you.

Comment: this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Getting_Started/Boxes might help you to under stand ...

Comment: Am I correct in seeing this only happening in Chrome, FF and IE seem OK, correct?

Comment: @ToddBFisher : Yes you are correct issue in chrome,safari only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving it a `border-right: 1px solid transparent;` as suggested here: [webkit renders last px of border:1px dotted; oddly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838223/webkit-renders-last-px-of-border1px-dotted-oddly)

[Updated your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmvVH/3/)

Comment: but it goes as 201px totally but a quick fix for the situation. thanks

Answer (score 0):

use

```
width:200px;
```

i think both r same 
[pls check](http://jsfiddle.net/mmvVH/4/)

Comment: still have the merged ends